# update formula to add functions of covariates

Tags: r, formula

Suppose that we have a formula

```
f1 <- y ~ x1
```

and that we need to add to it the covariate `sin(2*pi*x2)` using a function that will take as argument `x2`.

Of course, this works: `update(f1, . ~ . + sin(2 * pi * x2)` but I need a function likes this one

```
updf <- function(formula, x){
    formula <- update(formula, paste("~ . +", sin(2 * pi * x)))
    formula}
```

and the call `updf(f1,"x2")` will return: `y ~ x1 + sin(2 * pi * x2)`. This call returns "Error in 2 * pi * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator".

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: IF "x" is a string with the name of the variable: `formula <- update(formula, paste("~ . + sin(2 * pi * ", x, ")"))` should do the trick.

Comment: @Oliver Yes, it does do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` is a string with the name of the variable then `formula <- update(formula, paste("~ . + sin(2 * pi * ", x, ")"))` should work.

```r
f1 <- y ~ x1

updf <- function(formula, x){
  formula <- update(formula, paste("~ . + sin(2 * pi * ", x, ")"))
  formula
}  

updf(f1, "x2")
#> y ~ x1 + sin(2 * pi * x2)
```

---

<sup>This answer comes from @Oliver's comment and was posted more than a month after. I don't want to steal credit, I just want this question to stop appearing as "unanswered" while it is actually answered.</sup>